# SSH freezes or won't even login

Tags: ssh, openssh

On a private network with a machine with private IP address `10.0.0.2` and a machine with `10.0.0.12` I encounter problems with SSH from `10.0.0.2 -> 10.0.0.12`.
The machine on `10.0.0.12` regularly freezes some time after login (matter of seconds) or I can't even login to it. When I can't login, the last two lines of the output using `-vvv` are:

```
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.0.12 [10.0.0.12] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
```

And once connected using the `-vvv` option, these messages get printed in console:

```
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 82
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 82
```

If I'm correct these are:

```
SSH_MSG_GLOBAL_REQUEST                  80     [SSH-CONNECT]
SSH_MSG_REQUEST_FAILURE                 82     [SSH-CONNECT]
```

But that doesn't really give me a clue what could be the problem.

The server at `10.0.0.12` also has a public IP address. SSH directly to that IP address shows no problems at all.

Could there be a setting issue on the client or server machine that causes the problems?

Answer (score 1):

Probably found the issue, my own fault. Configured two systems with the same private IP address. Looks stable for now.